# How to simplify a differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

Now I get a differential equation like this:

```
(-1 + x) (1 + x)^2 == (2 (1 + x^2) (1 + x^4))/(-2 x (1 + x + x F[x]) + (-1 + x^3) F'[x])
```

I want to get the standard form like this:
$F'[x]+h(x)F[x]=g(x)$.
Are there any commands to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just showing a way to get$g(x)$ and $h(x)$:

```
exp = 2 (1 + x^2) (1 + x^4)/(-2 x (1 + x + x f) + (-1 + x^3) g);
gs = Collect[g /. First@Solve[exp == (x - 1) (1 + x)^2, g], f];
ans = u'[x] == gs /. f -> u[x];
{g[x], h[x]} = {1, -1} ({{0}, {1}} /. 
     FullSimplify[CoefficientRules[ans[[2]], u[x]]]);
TraditionalForm[Grid[
  {{"DE", ans},
   {"h[x]", h[x]},
   {"g[x]", g[x]}
   }, Frame -> All, BaseStyle -> 20]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
eq = (-1 + x)(1 + x)^2==(2 (1 + x^2)(1 + x^4))/(-2 x (1 + x + x F[x]) + (-1 + x^3) F'[x]);

Collect[Solve[eq, F'@x][[1, 1]], F@x] /. (a_ -> b_ F[x] + c_) :> HoldForm[a - b F[x] == c]
```

[image]

Comment: Your method is also OK! But I can only accept one.

Comment: @user10709 You can give me an upvote by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png) to heal my heart T_T